# Properties of $C_{p}([0,1])$

Tags: general-topology

Earlier this year, thanks to various users on this site, I was able to answer a question dealing with the properties of $C_{p}([0,1])$ here: [Properties of Cp(X)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83815/properties-of-cpx).

$C_{p}([0,1])$  is the space of all continuous real-valued functions on $[0,1]$ with the topology of point-wise convergence.

I was looking at problems dealing with this space, and I came across these two:

> Prove that the space $C_{p}([0,1])$ is Lindelöf.
>
> Is $C_{p}([0,1])$ normal?

Can anyone help me out with this one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you find a Lindelöf space that maps continuously onto $C_p[0,1]$? (Hint: there is one in the thread you link to). Recall (or prove): if $X$ is Lindelöf and $Y$ is regular and $f\colon X \to Y$ is continuous then $Y$ is Lindelöf.

Comment: If you show it is Lindelöf, then (every $C_{p}(X)$ being regular, even completely regular) it is also normal. So it's only the first that you need to concern yourself with.

Comment: Hint: if $X$ has a countable network, so does $C_p(X)$. A network is like a base, but the members need not be open sets. A regular space with a countable network is Lindelöf...

Comment: @t.b. I'm not seeing which space you are talking about from the thread I linked to. Can you give me any more hints or suggestions?

Comment: The space $C[0,1]$ with the $\sup$-norm is a separable Banach space, hence second countable and thus Lindelöf. The identity mapping $C[0,1] \to C_p[0,1]$ is continuous.

Comment: @t.b. Thank you! You have helped me greatly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I would argue (summarizing the comments):

1. The space $C[0,1]$ with the $\sup$-norm is a separable Banach space, hence it is second countable and thus Lindelöf. The identity mapping $C[0,1] \to C_p[0,1]$ is a continuous bijection, so $C_p[0,1]$ is Lindelöf (if your definition of Lindelöf includes regular, use the first sentence in 2. in addition).
2. $C_p[0,1]$ is regular because it is $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ with the product topology. A regular Lindelöf space is paracompact and hence normal.

Alternatively for 1., you could take the route suggested by Henno in the comments and prove the stronger property that $C_p[0,1]$ has a countable network, hence it is Lindelöf.